# How to find minimum value not in a integer field

Tags: mysql

In mysql database table I have integer field, what i want to find missing minimum value of the sequence.

Please Help.

```
1,2,3,5,6,8,....
missing is 4
```

Comment: Do you have an integer column, and you want the smallest integer that there is no row for OR do you have text column with comma separated integer?

Comment: Probably you want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-to-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT  val + 1
FROM    mytable t1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT NULL FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.val = t1.val + 1)
ORDER BY val
LIMIT 1
```