# (My)SQL: SELECT first number not taken in series of numbers, similar to MAX()

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I was wondering if there is any way to SELECT the first number that is not taken in a series of numbers, similar like you use MAX() to select the highest number.

Let's say you have a column "id", and you insert 1,2,3,5,6,8,10,...

If you use MAX() it will return 10. Is there a way to SELECT 4 (as it is the first free number), fill 4 and then SELECT 7 (5,6 are taken already, so 7 would be the next...)

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find a "gap" in running counter with SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-to-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql)

Comment: oh, thank you Sergio! I knew this question must have been asked somewhere but could not figure out those key words to search for :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it -

```
SELECT t1.id + 1
FROM tbl t1
LEFT JOIN tbl t2
    ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Note, that this won´t find free ids below the lowest id already existing in the table.
e.g. Having a table with the id: 234, 236, 237, it returns 235 instead of 1

Answer (score 3):

try this query

```
SELECT MIN(table0.id)+1 AS newid
FROM tst AS table0
LEFT JOIN tst table1 ON table1.id=table0.id+1
WHERE table1.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modification of Dojo's answer. It avoids using multiple resultsets.

```
set @i=0;
select max(if(@i=id,@i:=id+1,@i)) from tb1 order by id;
```

I like this answer better because it gives me the option to have a starting point where to begin looking for a missing number.

Comment: Works like a charm, love this answer

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? If you are trying to create unique id for a new row to be inserted, then there are better ways to do it.

You can do what nnichols suggested or you can do this if you don't want joins:

```
set @i=0;
select if(@i=id,@i:=id+1,@i) from tb1 order by id;
select @i;
```

Very useful if you have a large table and don't want a join.

Note: This returns multiple resultsets. Your app code should use the correct one.
Multiline queries may be disabled by default for security reasons, you will have to  override those settings (with caution) in the driver or the database config.

Comment: thx, Priyank... what language is this? I use php and mysql... have never seen this, that's why I ask :)

Comment: this is SQL that can run on MySQL. @i is a session variable so even if another thread fires the same query, it uses a different copy of @i