# Find Unused ID in Database using C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to code a simple database management tool in C#. I am in the process of coding a function to insert a new row into the database, but I have run into a problem. I need to be able to detect which ID numbers are not already taken. I have done some research but haven't found any clear answers.

```
Example table:
ID    Name
---------------
1     John
2     Linda
4     Mark
5     Jessica
```

How would I add a function that automatically detects that ID 3 is empty, and places a new entry there?

**Edit: My real question is; When I want to insert a new row via C#, how do I handle a column which is auto-increment? An example would be fantastic :)**

Comment: I am aware I could do some sort of loop that runs an IF EXISTS sql statement for each row, but I get that feeling that isn't the most efficient solution, and will probably slow things down when the database gets larger.

Comment: why not autoincrement the column values?

Comment: The issue you would have with `IF EXISTS` is that by the time the query has run and returned the result may be stale. As others have said, just auto increment.

Comment: How do I do that? Please add as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT      #temp.Id
FROM        #temp
LEFT JOIN   table1 ON #temp.Id = table1.Id
WHERE       table1.Id IS NULL
```

Try this?

But my suggestion is, just autoincrement the field.

How you do that is, you set the IDENTITY property of the column to true, and set it as Primary key too(not null).

To handle inserts, you might need triggers, which are like stored procedures, but they can act in place of insert or update or delete, or before/after insert/update/delete

Google triggers.

Comment: What is the `#temp` in this case?

Comment: a temporary table @LukeHennerley

Comment: Thanks, the column is already set up like this. My problem (which clearly I haven't explained properly) is that I don't know how to handle an insert into this table via C#. I can run SQL commands through C# fine so the syntax is not a problem for me - but what should I do with regards to the ID column? Obviously I can't insert an explicit value.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like giving answers like this...but I am going to anyway on this occasion.

**Don't**

What if you store more data in another table which has a foreign key to the ID in this table? If you reuse numbers you are asking for trouble with referential integrity down the line.

I assume your field is an int? If so, an auto increment should give more than enough for most purposes. It makes your insert simpler, and maintains integrity.

**Edit:** You might have a very good reason to do it, but I wanted to make the point in case somebody comes along and sees this later on who thinks it is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, thats very helpful. Now I just need to know how to auto-increment the value. (Yes its an int)

Comment: What type of SQL is it? Let me know and I will let you know how to auto increment :0)

Answer (score 1):

SQL:

```
SELECT ID From TABLE
```

**OR**

```
SELECT  t.ID
FROM    ( SELECT    number + 1 AS ID
          FROM      master.dbo.spt_values
          WHERE     Type = 'p'
                    AND number <= ( SELECT  MAX(ID) - 1
                                    FROM    @Table
                                  )
        ) t
        LEFT JOIN @Table ON t.ID = [@Table].ID
WHERE   [@Table].ID IS NULL
```

C#

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//Populate Dt with SQL
var tableInts = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row.Field<int>("ID")).ToList<int>();
var allInts = Enumerable.Range(1, tableInts.Max()).ToList();
var minInt = allInts.Except(tableInts).Min();
```

Comment: I am interfacing SQL Server to Java

Comment: @Aniket Huh? What does Java have to do with any of this question? OP states `C#` and `SQL`?

Comment: I was kidding, I wanted you to answer in SQL only. Switching languages is counter-productive.

Comment: @Aniket Okay haha, did it in SQL too

Comment: :-) cool @LukeHennerley. This way, you can keep SQL specific stuff in SQL and language specific stuff in the language itself. Let me give you +1 for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

from [How do I find a "gap" in running counter with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-to-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql/17431748#17431748)

```
select
    MIN(ID)
from (
    select
        0 ID
    union all
    select
        [YourIdColumn]+1
    from
        [YourTable]
    where
        --Filter the rest of your key--
    ) foo
left join
    [YourTable]
    on [YourIdColumn]=ID
    and --Filter the rest of your key--
where
    [YourIdColumn] is null
```