# How to find a gap in range in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-to-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql) explains how to find the first "unused" number in a table, but how can I find the same so that I can define extra constraints. How do I alter the query so that I get the first unused number after that's greater than 100

e.g. If I have 23, 56, 100, 101, 103 in my table i should get 102.

Comment: Include a `where mo.id > 100` condition (in any of the queries in the accepted answer).

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: At the moment I'm using SQLite, but will most likely be migrating to PostgreSQL later on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in mysql and postgresql

```
SELECT  id + 1
FROM    test mo
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    test mi 
        WHERE   mi.id = mo.id + 1
        ) and mo.id> 100
ORDER BY
        id
LIMIT 1
```

[fiddle for mysql](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43771/6) and [fiddle for postgresql](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/43771/1)

in ms sql

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        id + 1
FROM    test mo
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    test mi 
        WHERE   mi.id = mo.id + 1
        )
          and mo.id > 100
ORDER BY
        id
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43771/1)

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle Sql, you may try:

```
SELECT id
FROM
     (SELECT ID, lead(ID) OVER(ORDER BY ID) next_val FROM my_table t
     )
WHERE id +1 <> next_val
 AND id      >100;
```

Comment: That is in fact not Oracle specific. It uses standard ANSI SQL window function which would also work in Postgres, SQL Server 2012, DB2 and many other modern DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help you

```
SELECT MIN (id) + 1
  FROM myTable T1
 WHERE id >= 100
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM myTable T2
                    WHERE T1.id + 1 = T2.id)
```

Comment: Works quite well, except if id 101 is free and 1000 the first taken, I will get 1001 for some weird reason....

Comment: In this case, you must replace "id > 100" by "id >= 100" as shown in the query

Answer (score 0):

Using generate_series() for fun & profit:

```
CREATE table islands (num INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO islands (num ) VALUES
(23), (56), (100), (101), (103) ;

WITH total AS (
        SELECT generate_series(mima.bot, mima.top) AS num
        FROM ( SELECT MIN(num) AS bot , MAX(num) AS top FROM islands) mima
        )
SELECT num
FROM total tt
WHERE num >=100
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM islands ii
        WHERE ii.num = tt.num
        )
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a1.id + 1 FROM test a1 left JOIN test a2 
ON a1.id = a2.id - 1 
WHERE a2.id IS NULL AND a1.id > 100
```