# How to get the max sequential value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, enumeration

Having a table with a column that represents a enumeration:

**CASE 1**

```
| CustomID | Values |
|     '001'|     ...|
|     '002'|     ...|
|     '005'|     ...|
|     '006'|     ...|
```

I need to get the max value in sequential order, in this case: `'002'`

```
| CustomID | Values |
|     '028'|     ...|
|     '029'|     ...|
|     '031'|     ...|
|     '032'|     ...|
```

Result expected: `'029'`.

**CASE 2**
But if the data is like this:

```
| CustomID | Values |
|     '001'|     ...|
|     '002'|     ...|
|     '003'|     ...|
|     '004'|     ...|
```

I need to get `'004'`.

Comment: Gaps and islands problem. You need first gap - 1

Comment: Really not a good idea to be storing numbers as strings.  For one thing, it's going to make this a lot slower...

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I cannot edit the column type. The table already exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a "gap" in running counter with SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-to-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql)

Answer (score 1):

You need the first time that a gap is not one.  Assuming the values are actually numbers, the easiest way is to use `lead()`:

```
select min(t.customId)
from (select t.*,
             lead(customId) over (order by CustomId) as next_customId
      from t
     ) t
where next_CustomId is null or next_CustomId <> CustomId + 1;
```

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you can do the same thing with `outer apply`:

```
select min(t.customId)
from (select t.*,
             next.customId as next_customId
      from t outer apply
           (select top 1 t2.*
            from t t2
            where t2.CustomId > t.CustomId
            order by t2.CustomId
           ) next
     ) t
where next_CustomId is null or next_CustomId <> CustomId + 1;
```

Comment: Assuming he's got a later version of SQL Server that has `LEAD()` of course (can't remember, was it SQL Server 2012?)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Lead does not exists in SQL Server 2008

Comment: @ErickAstoOblitas . . . The question was not tagged SQL Server 2008 when I answered it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
;WITH cte As
(
    SELECT CAST(CustomID As INT) As cid FROM yourTable
)
SELECT MIN(cid) As MaxSeq
FROM   cte As c1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(Select * From cte As c2 Where c2.cid = c1.cid+1)
;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for windowed function/cte/subqueries. You can use simple `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT MIN(t.CustomID)
FROM #tab t
LEFT JOIN #tab t1
  ON t.CustomID = t1.CustomID - 1
WHERE t1.CustomID IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/401171)**</kbd>

You need to find first record that does not have consecutive record. Using self outer join and where you will get records that don't have consecutive records and `MIN` to get first of them.

Comment: **For funny downvoter, leave a comment why this code is bad**

Comment: not the down voter but if you try your solution with `INSERT INTO #tab VALUES ('001'),('002'),('003'),('005'),('006')` , it should return `004` but it doesnt :)

Comment: @M.Ali It should return `003`. It is the first gap - 1. Max sequential value starting from beginning. Check OP examples. Am I right?

Comment: read my comment again, if you insert the value `003` in the table it will still return `003` I think.

Comment: @M.Ali I run your [example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/401179) and it return `003` why  is it wrong? OP doesn't want first gap which is 004. Check first OP example `('001', '002', '005', '006')` => `'002'` not `'003'`