# How to get the min value from the missing ordred values in a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following integer values in a column `[1,2,3,4,6,7,9,11,12]`, I want to write a query that gives me the minimum positive missing integer that should be `5` in this case

thank you

Comment: [How do I find a “gap” in running counter with SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-do-i-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select min(t.col) + 1
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col = t.col + 1);
```

EDIT:

If I assume that you want "1" if it is missing from the sequence, then:

```
select (case when max(tm.mincol) > 1 then 1
             else min(t.col) + 1
        end) as first_missing
from t cross join
     (select min(col) as mincol, max(col) as maxcol
      from t
     ) tm
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col = t.col + 1);
```

Comment: select (case when max(tm.REF) > 1 then 1
             else min(gbs_don.REF) + 1
        end) as first_missing
from gbs_don cross join
     (select min(REF) as mincol, max(REF) as maxcol
      from gbs_don
     ) tm
where not exists (select 1 from gbs_don t2 where t2.REF = t.REF + 1);

Comment: above my SQL Query that gives me an error : unknown column tm.REF