# How do I find a gap in running counter in Informix table

Tags: sql, database, informix

How to find the first "gap" in auto increment column in an Informix`table.

For example:

My table `mission` like that:

```
emp_num  serial_request  year_request
33         45            2012
667        46            2012
588        50            2012
78         53            2012
89         33            2013
```

---

I want the first gap in `2012` ----> `47`

I have searched and found the following question:

[How do I find a “gap” in running counter with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1312101/418343)
 but the answer doesn't cover Informix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected answers for the other question only need trivial modifications to work with Informix.

For instance — one solution given in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1312101) is:

```
SELECT  id + 1
FROM    mytable mo
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    mytable mi 
        WHERE   mi.id = mo.id + 1
        )
ORDER BY
        id
LIMIT 1
```

The Informix equivalent, adapted to your schema, is:

```
SELECT LIMIT 1 serial_request + 1 AS id
  FROM mission AS m1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
          FROM mission AS m2 
         WHERE m2.serial_request = m1.serial_request + 1
       )
 ORDER BY id
```

Given the sample data, it correctly produces the answer 34 (the first number missing after a number that appears in the table).  To get the first number missing after a row entered in 2012, you simply need to add a condition:

```
   AND m1.year_request = 2012
```

Leading to:

```
SELECT LIMIT 1 serial_request + 1 AS id
  FROM mission AS m1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
          FROM mission AS m2 
         WHERE m2.serial_request = m1.serial_request + 1
       )
   AND m1.year_request = 2012
 ORDER BY id
```

That does yield the answer `47` as requested.

You could also use the OLAP windowing functions solution (again, based on SQL from the other question):

```
SELECT LIMIT 1
       q.previd + 1
  FROM (SELECT serial_request,
               LAG(serial_request) OVER (ORDER BY serial_request) previd
          FROM mission
         WHERE year_request = 2012
       ) AS q
 WHERE q.previd <> q.serial_request - 1
 ORDER BY q.previd;
```

This yields 47 too.  We can debate about the relative merits of the plus and minus `1` in the code and where they should go.

---

#### Test Schema and Data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mission;

CREATE TEMP TABLE mission
(
    emp_num         INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    serial_request  SERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    year_request    SMALLINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mission(emp_num, serial_request, year_request) VALUES(33, 45, 2012);
INSERT INTO mission(emp_num, serial_request, year_request) VALUES(667, 46, 2012);
INSERT INTO mission(emp_num, serial_request, year_request) VALUES(588, 50, 2012);
INSERT INTO mission(emp_num, serial_request, year_request) VALUES(78, 53, 2012);
INSERT INTO mission(emp_num, serial_request, year_request) VALUES(89, 33, 2013);
```

Testing: Informix 12.10.FC5 running on Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: You are just amazing :O