# Find the row that doesn't exists in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table, there are values for poster_display_no 1 and 3 but not 2. I want to fetch the poster_display_no that doesnt exists in the table. The below query is not working as expected. Any idea what is wrong in the above query?

```
select `poster_display_no` as missing_num 
from `poster-judging-app`.poster_details 
where `poster_display_no` not in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: You cannot fetch what is not there

Comment: I want to pass a list of poster_display_no and find which is not there in the table. Is that not possible?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in the title. I changed the title. I need to find the row that doesn't exists in the table.

Comment: Not really. I mean, all things are possible, but an RDBMS is primarily for the storage and retrieval of data. For other things, we have application code. And don't include mathematical operators in table/column identifiers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find a "gap" in running counter with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-do-i-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql)

Comment: @Strawberry. Thanks for your suggestion. It makes sense. I could have approached your way too. `select  poster_display_no from  poster-judging-app.poster_details where poster_display_no in (1,2,3)` and handle the missing value logic in the application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a hack, but you could build a derived table with the list of `poster_display_no`s that you want to chek for,  `left join` with your table and filter on the missing ones:

```
select t.poster_display_no
from (
    select 1 poster_display_no
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
) t
left join poster_details p on p.poster_display_no = t.poster_display_no
where p.poster_display_no is null
```

Another, more scalable option would be to create a separate referential table to store the list of `poster_display_no`s that you want to check for, and then bring that table directly to the query.

Comment: The @GMB idea of joining with the is null check is correct: select all the possible 1,2,3 values left join the `poster-details` table where the `poster-details`.`poster_display_no` table column is null retrieves the missing values

SELECT num FROM
( SELECT 1 AS num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 ) AS temp
LEFT JOIN poster-details ON (num=poster_display_no)
WHERE poster_display_no IS NULL;