# Performant way to fill gaps in a SQL table, partly read into an unordered map (SQL/C++)

Tags: c++, mysql

**The problem**
There is currently a system that reads unique identifiers (`id`) and their attached datasets from an SQL table into an unordered map. These datasets used to start with `id` 1, but datasets are added and deleted in a matter of ~10ms. Note that not all datasets are loaded into RAM at all times.

When the program is started, it reads  `SELECT MAX(id)` from the database and continues adding +1 to a counter variable, which it is using as `id` for any added dataset. The `id`s of deleted datasets are not used anywhere any more. This inevitably leads to gaps in the `id` sequence and an overflow someday.

I am looking for a performant way to fill the lowest gap of the `id` value. While remaining consistent with the only partly loaded SQL table and the program's memory. The data in the memory might not be saved to the SQL table for a few minutes or immediately.

**The idea**
One solution I came up with is to keep doing expensive queries at runtime for every created dataset to find the lowest gap in the SQL table, check if this `id` exists as a value in the unordered map, and then again use the value from the counter variable as a backup to avoid endless queries for a free `id`. This works exactly for the amount of 1 `id`. Then it's still free in SQL but taken in the unordered map until the memory is saved again.

I've also brainstormed doing queries for lists of free IDs into a vector and using them as `id` for new datasets until the vector is empty, then (or frequently) doing a new query for more IDs. But I can't think of a query to find X amount of gaps in a table, which may or may not have its `id` column starting with 1.

I've come across [How do I find a "gap" in running counter with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-do-i-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql) , but I have two issues with the top answer: Apparently, it only finds a single gap, while I would need lots and I can't make sense of the `mo` and `mi` it uses.

Let's say I have a table named `userdata` with the columns `id` and `dataset`, both 32-bit signed INT. How could I find an array of gaps in the `id` column? As an example, i want the query to return 2,3,4,5,8 when the `id`s in the table are 1,6,7,9.

Any pointers to an approach with a possible solution are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one database change each 10ms, then you have 100 changes per second. A signed `int` can hold about 2,147,483,648 values, or 21,474,846 seconds, which is about 8 months. After this, no available new ID is possible.

The first solution is using a `64bit` type instead of a `int`. This gives you about 13,600 years (for a signed 64b), which seems enough :)

---

**Other solution** is having a vector with all possible IDs. The vector stores `bool` (ID is used/unused). Requesting a new ID is done by travelling the vector up to the first position marked as unused.

This vector uses a lot of RAM, although std::vector has a specialized version for bools that requires less RAM.

---

**A third solution** is handling a linked list (maybe double linked) which stores the deleted (read: re-usable) IDs.

When a new ID is requested, the list offers its head, or the size of the table if the list is empty.

When a dataset is deleted its ID is properly inserted in the list, so the list is always sorted.

 When a ID is reused it's deleted from the list.

 Deleting the last record in the table may also delete last nodes in the list, as they are useless (case ID > table size). That's why I suggested using a double linked list, so as to delete quickly last nodes.

So, this list is quickly using "new" & "delete" on its nodes, and also frequently running up and down (for double linked) for inserting new nodes.

This is a bit slow, but I hope the list not to be too large, and the time required then is not that bad.

Also notice that this list gives you the array of gaps you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT MAX(id)` -- This technique will *not* be reliable if multiple concurrent processes are using it.  Let `AUTO_INCREMENT` do the work for you -- faster, more efficient, *and* safe for concurrency.

"gaps in the id" -- So?

Plan A:  Use `BIGINT` -- that has a limit so large that it would take many centuries to reach, even with the fastest machine today.

Plan B:  Let's discuss the dataflow.  There may be other techniques to avoid the gaps or deal with them.  For example, here is code to avoid "burning ids" for batch [*Normalization*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization)

Plan C:  As you say, filling in the gaps is too costly to even consider.