# Lowest unused ID from two combined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query to find the lowest available/unused ID from a column named `internal` that exists in two separate tables:

1. **machines**
2. **machines_ignore**

Data is processed from an external source, and we want to fetch data from all machines that are **not** in the `machines_ignore` table. The ignore table is just a manual table set up by us when we identify machines we don't want to analyze.

I've found scripts that work on a single table (like only the **machines** table), but as soon as I try to get it working when combining two tables.

### Example

#### Table 1 (machines)

| id | internal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |

#### Table 2 (machines_ignore)

| internal |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 12 |

#### Expected result

Based on the example above, this query should output 10, 11, 13 etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post sample data and expected result.

Comment: Thanks @SalmanA - I've done that now.

Comment: Are you using mySQL 8 or later by any chance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25719885/12181863 try taking a look at this answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to combine the values from both tables then check if each value has next value in both tables using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT x.internal + 1
FROM (
    SELECT internal FROM machines
    UNION
    SELECT internal FROM machines_ignore
) AS x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM machines WHERE internal = x.internal + 1
) AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM machines_ignore WHERE internal = x.internal + 1
)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This gives me a NULL result, which is a possibility (there are machines with internal set to NULL). How would the query need to be changed in order to ignore NULLs?

Comment: Where internal is not null?

Comment: Yeah, my problem was where to put it. Works fine within the union subquery :) Thanks!

Comment: how would it work if both tables are missing 1 or 0? if it is retrieving based on values which does not have "next" value?

Comment: @yhstan adding a simple `union select 0` should fix it